# What is the meaning of a "regular open basis" for a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

Just wanting to check what a "regular open basis" is, and whether it is correct that every topological space has a regular open basis.

My reason for asking this is that I am reading "Universally Baire Sets of Reals" by Qi Feng, Menachem Magidor and Hugh Woodin, and they give a definition of $\lambda$-universally Baire set which refers to the notion of a regular open basis, and also it would seem that their claim that a set is universally Baire if and only if it is $\lambda$-universally Baire for all $\lambda$ would only be true if every topological space had a regular open basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular open set is one which equals the interior of its closure. See 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiregular_space.